# .htaccess redirect to another site

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

hello all i am building a url shortener site where we create smart short urls for any long url the short url looks like this reurl.in/anji89jd. whenever anyone clicks on this short url the user is directed to corrosponding long url which is stored in database and it is extracted by sql query on the index page everything is working good but i dont know how to direct the user to the long urls by htaccess

look if the short link is reurl.in/abcd then the index page is designed like this 
reurl.in/index.php?r=abcd and then it directs the page to new site if i type this url everyhing works well

but reurl.in/abcd dosent works 
please help me i know this can be done by .htaccess

i have tried like

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^index/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?r=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: based on your rule the user should go to `reurl.in/index/abcd` for it to work not `reurl.in/abcd`. remove the `index/` from the rule. Also I don't know why you'd need the `QSA` flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?r=$1 [L,QSA]
```